# Extract sub-string between two certain words using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I would like to extract sub-string between certain two words using java.

For example:

```
This is an important example about regex for my work.
```

I would like to extract everything between "`an`" and "`for`".

What I did so far is:

```
String sentence = "This is an important example about regex for my work and for me";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=an).*.(?=for)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);

boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("I found the text: " + matcher.group().toString());
    found = true;
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("I didn't found the text");
}
```

It works well.

But I want to do two additional things

1. If the sentence is: `This is an important example about regex for my work and for me.`
   I want to extract till the first "`for`" i.e. `important example about regex`
2. Some times I want to limit the number of words between the pattern to 3 words i.e. `important example about`

Any ideas please?

Comment: do you want the pattern only match if there are only 3 words between 'an' and 'for', or do you want only the 3 words regardless of the number of words in the match?

Comment: @Dragon8: I want only the 3 words regardless of the number of words in the match.

Comment: ok, then you can split the match afterwards with `someString.split(" ")`. it returns a array of Strings there each position is a word from your match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your first question, make it lazy. You can put a question mark after the quantifier and then the quantifier will match as less as possible.

```
(?<=an).*?(?=for)
```

I have no idea what the additional `.` at the end is good for in `.*.` its unnecessary.

For your second question you have to define what a "word" is. I would say here probably just a sequence of non whitespace followed by a whitespace. Something like this

```
\S+\s
```

and repeat this 3 times like this

```
(?<=an)\s(\S+\s){3}(?=for)
```

To ensure that the pattern mathces on whole words use word boundaries

```
(?<=\ban\b)\s(\S+\s){1,5}(?=\bfor\b)
```

See it [online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uf3m)

`{3}` will match exactly 3 for a minimum of 1 and a max of 3 do this `{1,3}`

**Alternative:**

As dma_k correctly stated in your case here its not necessary to use look behind and look ahead. See [here the Matcher documentation about groups](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29)

You can use capturing groups instead. Just put the part you want to extract in brackets and it will be put into a capturing group.

```
\ban\b(.*?)\bfor\b
```

See it [online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uf3j)

You can than access this group like this

```
System.out.println("I found the text: " + matcher.group(1).toString());
                                                        ^
```

You have only one pair of brackets, so its simple, just put a `1` into `matcher.group(1)` to access the first capturing group.

Comment: I also would advise not to use look ahead/behind syntax. Why to complicate things? `an\b(.*?)\bfor` will perfectly do the job.

Comment: As @dmk_k (thanks) correctly stated its not necessary to use advanced constructs here in your case, I updated my answer with a simpler solution.

Comment: @stema: thank you for your help. the second alternative does not work for me, I don't know why it couldn't find the text. another thing i want "an" to be the separate word "an" not a part from a word like in "and" or"important".

Comment: @Daisy I updated my solution adding `\b` word boundaries. I also added links to "Regexr", that is a nice online tool where you can test your regexes.

Comment: But i wonder why this is more easier than  look ahead/behind? and when shall i use  look ahead/behind?

Comment: @Daisy Here is an [explanation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) in a Perl tutorial, the behaviour of Perl lookarounds and those in Java is the same.

Comment: This (?<=an).*?(?=for) snippet works well, thank you. So how can i apply this sample right to left way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean, extract to string right to left side. As this question's example; first position is (for) second position is (an). So extracting process works back ways. My english is not good. Sorry.

Comment: @Kerberos Probably it is better if you ask a new question. Please describe detailed what you have as input and what you want to get as result (and of course what you have tried ;-)).

Comment: @AlexR, @sterna - I have 2 strings: "pcrid=37398932585&pmt=&plc=www.mamapedia.com" and "pcrid=1369865469&pmt=bb". I used the Pattern Matcher way of doing it to extract pcrid and pmt. While pcrid works fine, I'd like to know how to extract pmt. I did: `Pattern pmt = Pattern.compile("(?<=pmt=).*.(&*?)")` It returns '&plc=www.mamapedia.com' and 'bb' respectively. How do I rewrite `pmt` to make it retrieve, in the first case, nothing at all, and in any other case, only the alphabets that follow `pmt=` and to ignore any and all special characters that come after the end of the last character?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is "`an\\s+(.*?)\\s+for`". It extracts all characters between an and for ignoring white spaces (`\s+`). The question mark means "greedy". It is needed to prevent pattern `.*` to eat everything including word "for".

Comment: A question mark makes a quantifier ungreedy. You are missing the quantifier in your answer, so you are looking for an arbitrary character and made this optional with your Question mark.

Comment: @AlexR: thank you, it works but adding * like that: "an\\s+(.*?)\\s+for"

Answer (score 2):

public class SubStringBetween {

```
public static String subStringBetween(String sentence, String before, String after) {

    int startSub = SubStringBetween.subStringStartIndex(sentence, before);
    int stopSub = SubStringBetween.subStringEndIndex(sentence, after);

    String newWord = sentence.substring(startSub, stopSub);
    return newWord;
}

public static int subStringStartIndex(String sentence, String delimiterBeforeWord) {

    int startIndex = 0;
    String newWord = "";
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        newWord = "";

        if (sentence.charAt(i) == delimiterBeforeWord.charAt(0)) {
            startIndex = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < delimiterBeforeWord.length(); j++) {
                try {
                    if (sentence.charAt(startIndex) == delimiterBeforeWord.charAt(j)) {
                        newWord = newWord + sentence.charAt(startIndex);
                    }
                    startIndex++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
            if (newWord.equals(delimiterBeforeWord)) {
                x = startIndex;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}

public static int subStringEndIndex(String sentence, String delimiterAfterWord) {

    int startIndex = 0;
    String newWord = "";
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        newWord = "";

        if (sentence.charAt(i) == delimiterAfterWord.charAt(0)) {
            startIndex = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < delimiterAfterWord.length(); j++) {
                try {
                    if (sentence.charAt(startIndex) == delimiterAfterWord.charAt(j)) {
                        newWord = newWord + sentence.charAt(startIndex);
                    }
                    startIndex++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
            if (newWord.equals(delimiterAfterWord)) {
                x = startIndex;
                x = x - delimiterAfterWord.length();
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

}