# Extract sub-string between two certain words right to left side

Tags: c#, regex

**Example String**

```
This is an important example about regex for my work.
```

I can extract **important example about regex** with this `(?<=an).*?(?=for)` snippet. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062954/extract-sub-string-between-two-certain-words-using-regex-in-java)

But i would like to extract to string right to left side. According to this question's example; first position must be (for) second position must be (an).

I mean extracting process works back ways.

I tried what i want do as below codes in else İf case, but it doesn't work.

```
public string FnExtractString(string _QsString, string _QsStart, string _QsEnd, string _QsWay = "LR")
        {
            if (_QsWay == "LR")
                return Regex.Match(_QsString, @"(?<=" + _QsStart + ").*?(?=" + _QsEnd + ")").Value;
            else if (_QsWay == "RL")
                return Regex.Match(_QsString, @"(?=" + _QsStart + ").*?(<=" + _QsEnd + ")").Value;
            else
                return _QsString;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My real example as below

```
#Var|First String|ID_303#Var|Second String|ID_304#Var|Third String|DI_t55
```

When i pass two string to my method (for example **"|ID_304" and "#Var|"**) I would like to extract **"Second String"** but this example is little peace of my real string and my string is changeable.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-brackets-using-net

Comment: Thank you but that suggestions partially similar. I would like to extract string back way.

Comment: Maybe it's an option to reverse the string and the start and end strings before you match with regex?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Could you give the desired output of `FnExtractString` for a few cases?

Comment: Can you post an example to demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: @Kerberos: You need to `Regex.Escape` on the string passed into the function.

Comment: @nhahtdh can you give an example?

Comment: I've seen your edit. Is it correct that `FnExtractString("start", "end", "LR") = FnExtractString("end", "start", "RL")`? If so, you'd not need another regex for this.

Comment: @ John Willemse unfortunately reverse approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

No need for forward or backward lookahead!  You could just:

```
(.*)\san\s.*\sfor\s
```

The `\s` demands whitespace, so you don't match `an` import*an*t.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem in your current solution is that the string passed in contains special characters, which needs to be escaped with `Regex.Escape` before concatenation:

```
return Regex.Match(_QsString, @"(?<=" + Regex.Escape(_QsStart) + ").*?(?=" + Regex.Escape(_QsEnd) + ")").Value;
```

For your other requirement of matching `RL`, I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: My end string is "#Var|" and start string is  "ID_304" Also There are so many "#Var|" string in my whole string. Regex.Escape is not important for me now. According to this approach i would like to extract "Second String" from my string not "Third String". My English is not so good. I hope that this has been an explanatory

Comment: @Kerberos: Can a match ever contains `|`? If not, there is a solution. Otherwise, you need to define how to search for the the match.